# Inserting into another table the id of the first row sharing given values, and another value from each duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalization

Sorry about the title - I had a hard time phrasing it succinctly

So I have some data which is currently all in one table, and I want to have it be stored in two different tables. This is a simple version of my situation:

```
Person:
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName | City     |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | Billy     | Bob      | Toronto  |
| 2  | Billy     | Bob      | Mumbai   |
| 3  | Sally     | Ann      | Toronto  |
| 4  | Joe       | Hall     | New York |
| 5  | Joe       | Hall     | Boston   |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

So I have a bunch of people and their cities. I want to make it so a given combination of first/last name only occurs once, and a second table describes that name id <-> city combination, like so:

```
Person:
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | Billy     | Bob      |
| 3  | Sally     | Ann      |
| 4  | Joe       | Hall     |
+----+-----------+----------+
LivesIn:
+----------+----------+
| PersonId | City     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | Toronto  |
| 1        | Mumbai   |
| 3        | Toronto  |
| 4        | New York |
| 4        | Boston   |
+----------+----------+
```

My problem is: how do I select only the first instance of each name combination to insert into the second table? To move the data over exactly, I could do:

```
INSERT INTO LivesIn (PersonId, City)
SELECT Id, City
FROM Person
```

But that means `LivesIn` will still have two different `PersonId`s to the same name combination.

Comment: I would suggest you go one more step and create a city table. Then you have a CityPerson table which is nothing but the primary key from the City and Person tables. Otherwise you are repeating data over and over.

Comment: That is actually basically what I have - In reality, "City" is a GUID from another table. I just thought it would be simpler in the example to have text for that column. :)

Comment: haha good idea to KISS. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO LivesIn (PersonId, City)
select t1.id, t2.City
from 
(
  SELECT min(Id) as id, FirstName, LastName
  FROM Person
  GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
) t1
join person t2 on t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName 
              and t1.LastName = t2.LastName
```